# camel-spring-boot-starter: org.apache.camel or org.apache.camel.springboot groupId?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

According to [Camel Context starter](https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/latest/spring-boot.html#SpringBoot-CamelSpringBootStarter) one can use these:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version> <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version> <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

Seems to be no mistake, the artefacts exist in maven too:
[Camel SB Core Starters :: Spring Boot Starter](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.springboot/camel-spring-boot-starter)
[Spring Boot Starter :: Camel :: Spring Boot](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-spring-boot-starter)

Should one use both (in same project) or only one?
Otherwise when to use one and when another and why?

Comment: I believe you should use second dependency if you want to use camel specific configuration properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out Maven Central for both starter definition you will see that the `<groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>` is used [prior to Camel 3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-spring-boot-starter) while `<groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>` is used since [Camel 3 and onwards](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.springboot/camel-spring-boot-starter).

As such, depending on your Camel version you use, you either should use `<groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>` in case you are stuck with Camel 2.x or `<groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>` for Camel 3.x+

Answer (score 0):

Which version of a camel you want to use, depends on them.

Camel 3.0 and onwards use
**org.apache.camel.springboot**

Prior to Camel 3.o use
**org.apache.camel**